# Cursor don't generate unique id

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a problem with a program who generate a unique number for my procedure. I use this procedure until 9 year and has always worked. This is the code

```
DECLARE @PROG AS DECIMAL(20,0) 
DECLARE MYCURSOR CURSOR SCROLL_LOCKS FOR
SELECT PROG FROM PROGRESSIVI where sezione='DUCATO' AND ISTPR=5034
FOR UPDATE OF PROG
    OPEN MYCURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM MYCURSOR INTO @PROG
    if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        UPDATE PROGRESSIVI SET PROG = @PROG + 1
        WHERE CURRENT OF MYCURSOR 
        SELECT @PROG + 1
    END 
CLOSE MYCURSOR 
DEALLOCATE MYCURSOR
```

For two days users using the procedure at the same second create the SAME progressive and this involves a lot of problems. Could it be some kind of SQL Server update that creates this problem? It's SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This is called a "race condition". These types of designs can (and will) suffer them. Honestly, this smells like an XY Problem; The use of a Cursor and the fact you want to increment values over and over again in a table strongly implies design flaws.

Comment: The bug is the use of a cursor in the first place. SQL Server already offers IDENTITY to auto-generate sequential ID values. Supported versions (ie 2014 and later) offer the SEQUENCE type too

Comment: I think even 2008 supports `SEQUENCE` @PanagiotisKanavos (I think that was the version it was introduced with). If not, certainly 2012 has the functionality. Been a while since I've had to use (suffer) SQL Server 2008 now.

Comment: Also, sorry to knit pick, technically `IDENTITY` doesn't generate (guarantee) sequential values. It does, however, guarantee that the values will always increasing.  :)

Comment: @Larnu SEQUENCE was added in 2012. You have to dig to even find the old docs now

Comment: Thanks, @PanagiotisKanavos. Honestly couldn't remember, and a lot of the old 2008 docs have been removed. Personally don't like the "new" docs, where you have different pages for different version, rather than one that at the top says "SQL Server (2012 onwards); i find it much harder to to find out if something is on a version, as the *absence* of the page *implies* it's not on that version (which is far from the case, as [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2014) is definitely on 2014, and even 2005+).

Comment: 2008 is **completely** unsupported - plan your upgrade. And notice the lack of an order by clause in your select statement. Does this logic assume something important about which row of multiple rows is returned first (and is therefore updated as a result)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NEWSEQUENTIALID() keyword in sql. This keyword generate sequential Id for you type type of uniqueidentifier.

Please check below link :
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answers, but the problem is that now I can't replace the way I generate identifiers with a "sequence". I just want to understand why my procedure has ALWAYS worked and now it doesn't work anymore :(
Is there a way to fix the code I wrote before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Pure luck, nothing more.

Comment: :)) ok hope are a lucky Boy !